# integral on a half circle

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, line-integrals

I was very confused by this integral: $I=\int_\gamma\frac{1}{z^2} dz$, where $\gamma$ is the upper half of the unit circle. I know that when $\gamma$ is the unit circle, this would integrate to 0. Then I thought if we have $a+bi$ in the upper half, we also have $-a-bi$ in the lower half, and their square is the same. So by symmetry, we would have that the integral along the upper half equals the integral along the lower half. Then each of them would be 0, which obviously isn't the case. So I was wondering what I am missing here.
Thank you!

Comment: my g your only on about a quater with those numbers that are complex

Comment: It is not true that the upper half and lower half are the same, the upper right quarter is equal to the lower left quarter, and the upper left quarter is equal to the lower right quarter

Comment: @Riemann'sPointyNose Sorry I don't think I have understood it - based on your comments, doesn't the integral along upper right + upper left equal lower left + lower right?

Comment: @pumpig exactly yes, but in different order. Here you are just saying that going around the upper half anti-clockwise is the same as going clockwise around the lower half, which doesn't tell you anything since you can deduce this anyway from ${\int_{\gamma}z^{-2}dz = 0}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By definition, if the domain of $\gamma$ is $[a,b]$, then$$\int_\gamma\frac1{z^2}\,\mathrm dz=\int_a^b\frac{\gamma'(t)}{\gamma^2(t)}\,\mathrm dt$$and it seems to me that you are not taking that $\gamma'(t)$ into account.

To be more concrete, take $\gamma\colon[0,\pi]\longrightarrow\Bbb C$ defined by $\gamma(t)=e^{it}$ and take $\eta\colon[\pi,2\pi]\longrightarrow\Bbb C$ also defined by $\eta(t)=e^{it}$. Then\begin{align}\int_\eta\frac1{z^2}\,\mathrm dz&=\int_\pi^{2\pi}\frac{ie^{it}}{e^{2it}}\,\mathrm dt\\&=\int_0^\pi\frac{ie^{i(t+\pi)}}{e^{2i(t+\pi)}}\,\mathrm dt\\&=-\int_0^\pi\frac{ie^{it}}{e^{2it}}\,\mathrm dt,\end{align}since $e^{\pi i}=-1$ and $e^{2\pi i}=1$. But the final integral is just $\int_\gamma\frac1{z^2}\,\mathrm dz$.

The same argument applies if we have any even function instead of $z^2$.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was missing!

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

After the substitution $z=e^{i\theta} \rightarrow dz=ie^{i\theta}d\theta$, you're left with $I=i\int_0^\pi e^{-i\theta}d\theta=2$